# PayPal/Express/Review page Shipping auto selected

Tags: paypal-express

In Magento web site on the Review page of PayPal Express, the user needs to choose a shipping method.

We want from the list free shipping method should be selected. so place order should not be grayed out. so it should automatically selected `freeshipping_freeshipping`.